# Does UML have an XSD for it's XMI?

Tags: xml, xsd, uml

Is there a XSD for UML XMI files?

The header just contains namespace references.

```
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1"
    xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1"
    xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1"
    xmlns:thecustomprofile="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/thecustomprofile/1.0">
```

The only file I've managed to track down is this http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001/XMI.xsd however this is just description of the XMI itself (Difference/Documentation), but not the UML.

That means that I have no knowledge of how the process the following

```
<generalization
    xmi:type="uml:Generalization" 
    xmi:id="EAID_8CC13F09_BD19_406b_A4B4_37FB8B315EF0" 
    general="EAID_E1F9FAD6_2BDB_40ad_AAE2_E3935ADD1CDC"/>
```

as I have no way of knowing what is the type of `general` (of course I can check against a global ID table, but that seems stupid to do for every single attribute and TextElement).

I would expect to have something like

```
<xsd:complexType name="Generalization">
    <xsd:attribute name="general" type="xsd:IDREFS" use="optional"/>
    ...
</xsd:complexType>
```

Does the UML's XMI has such description?

Comment: You might send this question directly to Sparx. Usually they are quite helpful when it comes to this kind of questions. I would guess that `xml:is` is the guid of the generalizing class and `general` that of the general class.

Comment: @ThomasKilian well this is a question regarding UML as it would be the same for any tool that exports XMI — that's why I am surprised that there is no central XSD.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not much surprised. For years it was almost impossible to get the meta model. Even now, the meta model is more one to produce pictures for the PDF rather than being a meta model.

Comment: @ThomasKilian thanks! Writing to Sparx was indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging, my conclusion is not only that such XSD doesn't exist, but that it can't exist at all, because it is not powerful enough to properly express all the OCL constrains and rules of UML.

The correct approach should be to validate/process it through a conforming UML model, so the necessary information to properly process the XML has to be somehow derived from the model.

**Update:**

Per @Thomas' suggestion I wrote to Sparx and got the following response

> It's derived from the UML metamodel.
>
> No, we don't have an XSD for the XMI format.

Which confirms my assumption that the information should be derived from the metamodel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an official specification for XMI, including an XSD.
For the latest version ([v 2.5.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.5.1/)) this is the [xsd](http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001/XMI.xsd) but this xsd will not validate the UML syntax of the model.

The meta-model of UML is available as well in [xmi format](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20131001/UML.xmi)

More info on http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/

Comment: Well I have linked this particular XSD in the question itself and I've pointed out that it doesn't really address the problem I'm facing with UML, unless I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Both UML as XMI are formally defined. XMI is a more generic format for exchanging models, and as such it will not validate the UML syntax of the model contained in it. AFAIK there is no universal tool to validate a UML model, but the Meta-Model of UML (in xmi format) is available on the OMG site as well. I've edited the answer to reflect that.