# Scheme/XSD/spec for UML 2.2 as XMI

Tags: xsd, uml, xmi

UML models can be imported/exported as XMI, a XML-based UML exchange format.
I'm looking for any document that describes the syntax of such XMI files.

See below an extract of a XMI file which describes an interface with one operation inside a package :

```
<-- Package -->
<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="myPackage" name="myPackage">                    
    <!-- Interface -->
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Interface" name="IName" isAbstract="true" xmi:id="myPackage.IName">
        <!-- An operation of this interface -->
        <ownedOperation name="getSomething" visibility="public">
            <ownedParameter type="myPackage.Type" isUnique="false" direction="return">
            </ownedParameter>
        </ownedOperation>
    </packagedElement>
</packagedElement>
```

I'm looking for the document that describes the allowed `uml:Something` tags, their attributes, the allowed children elements, etc.

If you do not have the document or don't know where to find it, at least do you know the official name of such a document ? (this would help me in my endless quest...)

Right now, the only way I found to understand the syntax is to create a model using a modeling tool (such as Modelio or RSA), export it as XMI and analyze the result. Which is a bit too empirical.

Comment: Bad luck here. There is some "very general" documentation from OMG. But basically what can go in an XMI seems pretty much vendor dependent (for obvious reasons). You need to look into some individual exports. And unfortunately your question is OT.

Comment: I guess you already found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162752/saving-uml-model-as-xmi-ambiguity/50163570#50163570

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I found it just after posting my question. I'm still hoping maybe someone wrote something about this... A non-official article or specification.

Comment: What does "OT" means ? Isn't it weird that a format used to import and export UML models doesn't have a standard implementation ? What's the point of interchangeability if you get stuck with your vendor ?

Comment: OMG is a consortium of vendors. And they want their own sheep in their stable. Exchange means exchangeable within their product line, not with other vendors. That probably explains it. OT = Off Topic.